# Why does the "Python stop working" for this PyQt5 invoice GUI application when i clicked submit button?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

It will be pleasure for me if you can help me to solve this issue. I am practicing coding of PyQt5 Gui Application. This is the simple GUI application which generate invoice. But whenever i click submit(create invoice) button it stopped. I can't figure out the problem. Please help me to solve the problem.

Update: Can anyone fix the code with no error?
The Error message is:

```
>>> Exception "unhandled AttributeError"
'InvoiceForm' object has no attribute 'setCentralWidget'
```

The code has given below:-

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QSize, QSizeF, QDate
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextDocument, QTextCursor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QFormLayout, QLineEdit, QPlainTextEdit, QSpinBox, QDateEdit, QTableWidget, \
    QHeaderView, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QTextEdit, QApplication, QMainWindow


class InvoiceForm(QWidget):
    submitted = pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setLayout(QFormLayout())
        self.inputs = dict()
        self.inputs['Customer Name'] = QLineEdit()
        self.inputs['Customer Address'] = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.inputs['Invoice Date'] = QDateEdit(date=QDate.currentDate(), calendarPopup=True)
        self.inputs['Days until Due'] = QSpinBox()
        for label, widget in self.inputs.items():
            self.layout().addRow(label, widget)

        self.line_items = QTableWidget(rowCount=10, columnCount=3)
        self.line_items.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Job', 'Rate', 'Hours'])
        self.line_items.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.layout().addRow(self.line_items)
        for row in range(self.line_items.rowCount()):
            for col in range(self.line_items.columnCount()):
                if col > 0:
                    w = QSpinBox()
                    self.line_items.setCellWidget(row, col, w)

        submit = QPushButton('Create Invoice', clicked=self.on_submit)
        self.layout().addRow(submit)

    def on_submit(self):
        data = {'c_name': self.inputs['Customer Name'].text(),
                'c_addr': self.inputs['Customer Address'].toPlainText(),
                'i_date': self.inputs['Invoice Date'].date().toString(),
                'i_due': self.inputs['Invoice Date'].date().addDays(self.inputs['Days until Due'].value()).toString(),
                'i_terms': '{} days'.format(self.inputs['Days until Due'].value()),
                'line_items': list()}

        for row in range(self.line_items.rowCount()):
            if not self.line_items.item(row, 0):
                continue
            job = self.line_items.item(row, 0).text()
            rate = self.line_items.cellWidget(row, 1).value()
            hours = self.line_items.cellWidget(row, 2).value()
            total = rate * hours
            row_data = [job, rate, hours, total]
            if any(row_data):
                data['line_items'].append(row_data)

        data['total_due'] = sum(x[3] for x in data['line_items'])

        self.submitted.emit(data)
        main = QWidget()
        main.setLayout(QHBoxLayout())
        self.setCentralWidget(main)

        form = InvoiceForm()
        main.layout().addWidget(form)
        self.preview = InvoiceView()
        main.layout().addWidget(self.preview)
        form.submitted.connect(self.preview.build_invoice)

class InvoiceView(QTextEdit):
    dpi = 72
    doc_width = 8.5 * dpi
    doc_height = 11 * dpi

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(readOnly=True)
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(self.doc_width, self.doc_height))

    def build_invoice(self, data):
        document = QTextDocument()
        self.setDocument(document)
        document.setPageSize(QSizeF(self.doc_width, self.doc_height))
        cursor = QTextCursor(document)
        cursor.insertText("Invoice, woohoo!")

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = InvoiceForm()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: first you can use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in varibalbles. Maybe it runs long-running code and this blocks GUI and it can't work - so it freezes.

Comment: if program crushes then you should run in console to see error message - and add this error message in question (not comment) as text (not image)

Comment: Please be more careful when pasting code, and always ensure that it's formatted correctly in the question preview, otherwise we won't be able to distinguish from errors caused by wrong indentation. Read more on [formatting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362).

Comment: Thanks all of you. I have just updated the question. I am new in stackoverflow. Your comment help me a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your code in a shell/prompt, you'll clearly see the error:

```
>>> Exception "unhandled AttributeError"
'InvoiceForm' object has no attribute 'setCentralWidget'
```

The problem is that `setCentralWidget` is a function of QMainWindow, while you're using a simple QWidget.

While you could try to subclass `InvoiceForm` from QMainWindow and modify its layout and logic accordingly, it won't work very well, as you did some conceptual errors: the most important is trying to add a `InvoiceForm` instance to itself, but you also emitted the `submitted` signal *before* connecting it to `build_invoice`, so it won't work as expected.

The best solution is to create a QMainWindow subclass and add the instances of those widgets to it.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QSize, QSizeF, QDate
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextDocument, QTextCursor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QFormLayout, QLineEdit, QPlainTextEdit, QSpinBox, QDateEdit, QTableWidget, \
    QHeaderView, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QTextEdit, QApplication, QMainWindow


class InvoiceForm(QWidget):
    submitted = pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setLayout(QFormLayout())
        self.inputs = dict()
        self.inputs['Customer Name'] = QLineEdit()
        self.inputs['Customer Address'] = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.inputs['Invoice Date'] = QDateEdit(date=QDate.currentDate(), calendarPopup=True)
        self.inputs['Days until Due'] = QSpinBox()
        for label, widget in self.inputs.items():
            self.layout().addRow(label, widget)

        self.line_items = QTableWidget(rowCount=10, columnCount=3)
        self.line_items.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Job', 'Rate', 'Hours'])
        self.line_items.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.layout().addRow(self.line_items)
        for row in range(self.line_items.rowCount()):
            for col in range(self.line_items.columnCount()):
                if col > 0:
                    w = QSpinBox()
                    self.line_items.setCellWidget(row, col, w)

        submit = QPushButton('Create Invoice', clicked=self.on_submit)
        self.layout().addRow(submit)

    def on_submit(self):
        data = {'c_name': self.inputs['Customer Name'].text(),
                'c_addr': self.inputs['Customer Address'].toPlainText(),
                'i_date': self.inputs['Invoice Date'].date().toString(),
                'i_due': self.inputs['Invoice Date'].date().addDays(self.inputs['Days until Due'].value()).toString(),
                'i_terms': '{} days'.format(self.inputs['Days until Due'].value()),
                'line_items': list()}

        for row in range(self.line_items.rowCount()):
            if not self.line_items.item(row, 0):
                continue
            job = self.line_items.item(row, 0).text()
            rate = self.line_items.cellWidget(row, 1).value()
            hours = self.line_items.cellWidget(row, 2).value()
            total = rate * hours
            row_data = [job, rate, hours, total]
            if any(row_data):
                data['line_items'].append(row_data)

        data['total_due'] = sum(x[3] for x in data['line_items'])

        self.submitted.emit(data)
        # remove everything else in this function below this point


class InvoiceView(QTextEdit):
    # ...

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central)
        layout = QHBoxLayout(central)

        self.invoiceForm = InvoiceForm()
        layout.addWidget(self.invoiceForm)

        self.invoiceView = InvoiceView()
        layout.addWidget(self.invoiceView)
        # hide the widget right now...
        self.invoiceView.setVisible(False)

        self.invoiceForm.submitted.connect(self.showPreview)

    def showPreview(self, data):
        self.invoiceView.setVisible(True)
        self.invoiceView.build_invoice(data)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hello, As i am new in GUI, i can't understand you. I have copied the code from internet for study purpose. I failed to run. Could you fix the specific portion of code? Then, I will study the mistakes.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @MinarMahmud see the update.